# What is the portion marked by red called in Android Development?

Tags: android, listview

[image]

I am developing an Android App for TO DO List. I want to make clone of SplenDO which is present in Google play Store.The app looks like the above screenshot.What is the portion marked by red called,its definitely not an OptionsMenu and can somebody point me to the code how to include that in my app and when i choose Personal,items which i add in listview should be included in Personal and same for Default,Shopping,Worklist.

Comment: Looks like either a `Dialog` or `PopupWindow` containing a `ListView` or a `RecyclerView`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is a *CustomDialog* where you nest a *ListView* in it. Here is the [design pattern](https://material.io/guidelines/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-specs) and [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) on how to add List.

Hope it helps.